# Como faço para verificar se um número está contido em um intervalo de dois números?

Tags: javascript

Preciso verificar se o número 25 está contido no intervalo de dois números passados como parâmetro. a função retorna true caso 25 esteja contido no intervalo e false caso não esteja.

O problema é que não tem um número mínino e máximo que será passado como parâmetro, então não sei como fazer o if, se vier um 10 e um 30 era pra dar true mas tá dando false pois 30 é maior que 25 mas o 25 está contido no intervalo

```
function verifica25(x, y){
    if ((x <= 25) && (y <= 25)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/aqB8wD

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você tem que testar os limites

```
function verifica25(x, y){
  if( (x < y) && (x <= 25) && (25 <= y) ){
    return true;
  }
  else if( (y <= x) && (y <= 25) && (25 <= x) ){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```